# How do I find my entire feature update history in windows update?

Tags: windows-10, windows-update

How do I find my entire feature update history in windows update?
I don’t mean just the current feature update, but the entire history.

As in seeing the upgrade history from 1808 to 1903 to 20H2

Comment: Update history does not go back to the beginning - only the last year or eighteen months. This computer here has been running Windows 10 since about V1607.

Answer (score 1):

> How do I find my entire feature update history in windows update? I don’t mean just the current feature update, but the entire history.

Windows Update does not actually list updates from previous feature updates, it will only list applicable updates for the version that is installed, and the list of updates will be wiped once a feature update is released.  **So your desire to see which updates you installed on your previous version (1809, 1903) is not possible.**

However, due to the fact `Windows 10 version 1909` and `Windows 10 version 20H2` can both be installed through their respective enablement package, upgrading to those versions will not completely wipe your installation history.  Upon review my own Windows Update history, it showed me updates from before I installed the 20H2 enablement package, but since Windows continuously does maintenance to get rid of updates that are no longer required it doesn't show updates from when I initially upgraded to `Windows 10 version 2004`

I suspect that the only reason I even see updates from before I installed Windows 10 version 20H2 is due to the enablement package update that is installed.  However, if you were to install those versions with the Upgrade Assistance or the Media Creation Tool, I suspect the Windows Update history would be cleaned up.  **There is only a small difference between a custom installation and an upgrade to a new version of Windows.**

[image]

Source: [Windows Setup Process](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/windows-setup-installation-process#installationtypes)

Answer (score 0):

Windows Feature update history goes back about a year or so. It may depend on your actual installation.

For sure, it does not go back to the beginning. This computer here is from 2016 and came with V1607 thereabouts. My X230 converted to Windows 10 in 2015 and had the first production version of Windows 10.

Both machines show update history back about a year.

Here is a support article about this issue.

[Windows 10 Update History](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-update-winpc/update-history-windows-10-how-far-back-should-it/a1edb23a-72ed-482d-a4a1-46b48fdd8bc2?auth=1)

A post in 2017 says:

> The fuller list here goes back to the time the Anniversary Update was
> installed. Please note, however, that it only list current updates.
> Thus only seven updates are recorded for Windows.

That is about a far back then as I show now in 2021.